# Python: How to build a new column based on the partial string presence in another column in pandas?

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, count

I have a pandas df like this:

```
index   comments                                            
0       ['this is truthy', 'can this be truthy']            
1       ['falsy into falsy', 'that doesnot make it truthy']     
2       ['neutral game','neutral truth','falsy and truthy']
```

I want to create three new columns based on the count of these strings: "truthy", "falsy" and "neutral". The output should look like this:

```
index   comments                                            truthy  falsy   neutral 
0       ['this is truthy', 'can this be truthy']            2       0       0           
1       ['falsy into falsy', 'that doesnot make it truthy'] 1       2       0       
2       ['neutral game','neutral truth','falsy and truthy'] 1       1       2
```

What's an efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each row is a python `list`, then the following should come fairly close:

```
import pandas as pd

# Set up
df = pd.DataFrame()

lol = [['this is truthy', 'can this be truthy'],
      ['falsy into falsy', 'that doesnot make it truthy'],
      ['neutral game','neutral truth','falsy and truthy']]

df['comments'] = lol

adjectives = ['truthy', 'falsy', 'neutral']

# Solution
d = {k: df.comments.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x).count(k)) for k in adjectives}

df1 = df.assign(**d)

print(df1)

#                                           comments  falsy  neutral  truthy
# 0             [this is truthy, can this be truthy]      0        0       2
# 1  [falsy into falsy, that doesnot make it truthy]      2        0       1
# 2  [neutral game, neutral truth, falsy and truthy]      1        2       1
```

In essence, each row of the dataframe is joined together to form a string and you use that string to `count` the number of times an adjective is encountered. You use `.apply` to make both the joining and the counting and `.assign` is used to make sure that you are assigning the results of the join and count operations to their corresponding columns.

#### Edit to add cancellation column:

```
df1['cancellation'] = "does not cancel each other"
df1.loc[(df1.truthy - df1.falsy) <= 5] = "cancel each other"
```

`df1` should now have a column named `cancellation` where values are equal to "cancel each other" when `count(truthy) - count(falsy) <= 5` and "does not cancel each other" otherwise.

I hope this proves useful.

Comment: Damn, that was badass. You solved it in one line which I could not for a long time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @0x1 I'm glad this was helpful.

Comment: If I want to build two more columns for each row saying "cancel each other" and "does not cancel each other" if the difference between count(truthy) and count(falsy) is less than or equal to 5, then how should I proceed? Any ideas?

Comment: @0x1 why not just one column called `cancellation` and the values of that column would be "cancel each other" and "does not cancel each other" depending on your condition? Also, what condition matches which value?

Comment: Yes, actually one column would do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
df['truthy'] = df.comments.count('truthy');
df['falsy'] = df.comments.count('truthy');
df['neutral'] = df.comments.count('truthy');
```

Comment: I think the `count` string should differ.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html#pandas.Series.str.extractall) or [`count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html).

Sample data:

```
matches = ['truthy','falsy','neutral']
data = {"comments" :[['this is truthy', 'can this be truthy'],
                     ['falsy into falsy', 'that doesnot make it truthy'],
                     ['neutral game','neutral truth','falsy and truthy']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=matches)
df
                                                comments
truthy              [this is truthy, can this be truthy]
falsy    [falsy into falsy, that doesnot make it truthy]
neutral  [neutral game, neutral truth, falsy and truthy]
```

#### Approach 1

The Pandas Series string method `extractall` will keep track of each matching group. Then just count up the number of matches:

```
matches = ['truthy','falsy','neutral']
for i, d in enumerate(df.comments.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(' '.join(x)).str.extractall("(truthy)|(falsy)|(neutral)")).values):
    comment = d.notnull().sum()
    comment.index = matches
    print(df.comments[i])
    print(comment)
```

Output:

```
['this is truthy', 'can this be truthy']
truthy     2
falsy      0
neutral    0
dtype: int64
['falsy into falsy', 'that doesnot make it truthy']
truthy     1
falsy      2
neutral    0
dtype: int64
['neutral game', 'neutral truth', 'falsy and truthy']
truthy     1
falsy      1
neutral    2
dtype: int64
```

#### Approach 2

Use `str.count` with a list comprehension:

```
df.comments.apply(lambda x: [pd.Series(' '.join(x)).str.count(word) for word in matches])
truthy     [[2], [0], [0]]
falsy      [[1], [2], [0]]
neutral    [[1], [1], [2]]
Name: comments, dtype: object
```